# JSON handling error: Output not fetched correctly

Tags: ios, json, foreach, alamofire, swifty-json

I have the following JSON response. Currently, my POST request will give me "username" in my console output. However my alertView (found in handlingAuthentication, link provided) returns a nil when I run the app.

```
{
  "username" : [
  "The username field is required."
  ],
  "password" : [
  "The password field is required."
  ]
}
```

How do I :

- get the string "The username field is required"
- pass the string to my alertview in the method handlingAuthentication
- get multiple strings from the JSON response (E.g. Print in the AlertView: "The password field is required.*next line*The username field is required.")

**This is my POST request**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift

class Login {

init(userName: String, passWord: String) {
    Data.sharedInstance.userName = userName
    Data.sharedInstance.passWord = passWord
}

// call this method to login
func getRequest() {

    Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: ["username": Data.sharedInstance.userName!, "password": Data.sharedInstance.passWord!])
        .responseJSON { response in

            var errorFound = Bool()
            var errorMessage = String()

            if let result = response.result.value
            {
                let value = JSON(result)
                var outcome = String()

                //No username
                if value["password"] == nil && value["message"] == nil && value["name"] == nil
                {
                    errorFound = true
                    for output in value {
                        errorMessage = output.0
                        print(errorMessage)
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }

            let errorDict = ["error": errorFound, "message": errorMessage]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("errorPresent", object:errorDict)


    }

}


}
```

The code to where I display my alert message is here https://codeshare.io/VilQl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK first of all

```
if(errorFound as! NSObject == 1)
```

Should be giving you a warning as `if let errorFound = dict["error"]{` will already unwrap the errorFound so using as! is redundant :)

you can simply say

```
if(errorFound as NSObject == 1)
```

Second `let errorMessage = dict["message"]?.stringValue` this can be replaced as

```
let errorMessage : String! = dict["message"]! as! String
```

and in case you wanna check if dictionary has any value for key message or not

```
if let errorMessage = dict["message"] as? String{
     print("\(errorMessage)")
}
```

Now your alert should show properly :)

**EDIT**

as per your comment :)

```
if value["message"] == nil && value["name"] == nil
{
    errorFound = true
    errorMessage = value["username"][0]
    errorMessage += "\n"
    errorMessage += value["password"][0]
}
```

This should pass the data to next method :)

Comment: For my POST request, how do I get the "The username field is required"? I have tried output["username"] but I would be thrown a "Type Element has no subscript members" error.

Comment: I've tried doing this but I would be thrown a  "cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'String'" error

Comment: @noobdev : My bad can you try my updated answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
   var dict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSObject : AnyObject]() // your response here which you have print in question
    var arr: [AnyObject] = (dict["username"] as! [AnyObject])
    let str: String = arr[0] as! String
```

Then pass this string to alertview's message.

Hope this will help :)